# getting exception after webjob sdk code fork for public class ServiceBusTriggerAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I get all webjod sdk code from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk)

I want to make class `ServiceBusTriggerAttribute` public and non sealed and created nuget package using `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.dll`
but when I use this nuget in my webjob project getting below exception.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong
>   name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was recently discussed in the public repo [here](http://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/581). I don't think trying to subclass the attribute is the way to go. I suggested some alternatives in the github issue. You're getting the above exception because all the WebJobs SDK assemblies are delay signed (in project settings). They need to be fully signed for use.

Comment: perfect thanks but What I did is code download from github build Package project and install created nuget and now after running webjob getting error : No function found :(

Comment: how can I fully signed for use. I already have publicKey.snk in common folder but that doesnot work :(

Comment: If I use `JobHostConfiguration.INameResolver` also I want to pass parameters runtime not to use constants :(