# I have fork class ServiceBusTriggerAttribute to public and removed sealed - getting exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have taken a sdk code from [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk) and make fork `class ServiceBusTriggerAttribute.cs public removed sealed`.

```
namespace Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs
{
// Summary:
// Represents an attribute that binds a parameter to a Service Bus Queue message,
// causing the method to run when a message is enqueued.
//
// Remarks:
// The method parameter type can be one of the following: BrokeredMessage System.String
// byte[] A user-defined type (serialized as JSON)
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
[DebuggerDisplay("{DebuggerDisplay,nq}")]
public class ServiceBusTriggerAttribute : Attribute
```

and created 3 nugets from `.nuspec` files

```
WebJobs.Core.nuspec
WebJobs.nuspec
WebJobs.ServiceBus.nuspec
```

after installing these newly created packages when run my webjob I get following error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong
>   name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was already asked and discussed in a duplicate post here: [getting exception after webjob sdk code fork for public class ServiceBusTriggerAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475740/getting-exception-after-webjob-sdk-code-fork-for-public-class-servicebustriggera)